# PostgreSQL pg_restore error from pgadmin4 showing role doesn't exist

Tags: database, postgresql, database-backups

I am trying to restore a database from one schema to another schema in *postgresql* using *pgadmin* backup and restore utility. The backup is successful for the **database A** but when I try to do the restore of this to another **database B** I get the error as shown below.

Do anyone know about this or have faced an issue like this before?

I tried changing the restore options like

1. Do not save owner as yes
2. Privileges yes etc but still there was no luck.

**Sample:**

> pg_restore: creating TABLE "public.app_role" pg_restore: [archiver
>   (db)] Error from TOC entry 227; 1259 197811 TABLE app_role schedule
>   pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR: role
>   "schedule" does not exist Command was: ALTER TABLE public.app_role
>   OWNER TO schedule;

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, users and tablespaces are not part of the database, so they are not included in `pg_dump` output.

You'll have to run `pg_dumpall -g` to get a dump of these objects. Apply that dump first, then it should work.

Alternatively, use the options `-O -x` of `pg_restore` to skip restoring ownership and permissions. Then the objects will belong to the user who ran `pg_restore`.